# Creating lists and sets in Scala: What do I actually get?

Tags: list, scala, set, scala-collections

If I create a `Set` in Scala using `Set(1, 2, 3)` I get an `immutable.Set`.

```
scala> val s = Set(1, 2, 3)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

**Q1:** What kind of Set is this actually? Is it some hash-set? What is the complexity of look-ups for instance?

**Q2:** Where can I read up on this "set-creating" method? I thought that it was the `apply` method but the docs says "*This method allows sets to be interpreted as predicates. It returns true, iff this set contains element elem.*"

---

Similarly, if I create a `List` using `List(1, 2, 3)`, I get

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.getClass
res13: java.lang.Class[_] = class scala.$colon$colon
```

**Q3:** Again, what do I get? In this case I can't even immediately tell if it's mutable or not, since it's not even part of the `scala.collection`-package. Why does this live in the `scala` package?

**Q4:** Where in the API can I read about this "list-creating" method?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Q1: In this specific case you get a `Set3` which is an immutable set of exactly three arguments. Presumably it uses if-else if-else to check inclusion. If you create a set of more than 4 elements, you get an immutable hash set.

Q2: You need to look at the `apply` method of the object Set, not the class. The `apply` method of the Set class is what is called when you do `someSet(something)`.

Q3: [scala.::](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/$colon$colon.html) is a non-empty immutable singly linked list (if you do `List()` without arguments, you get `Nil` which is an immutable empty list). It lives in the `scala` package because it is considered so basic that it belongs in the base package.

Q4: See Q2.

Comment: Aah, thanks! You have a link for the `Set`-object that you mention? (I can only find the trait!)

Comment: @aiobe: Stackoverflow didn't like the `$` in the URL, so I edited to use tinyurl.

Comment: Oh, there it was. Wonder how I could have missed that. Thanks, you've been very helpful :)

Answer (score 13):

Just to add to sepp2k's excellent answer to Q3, where he says

> It lives in the `scala` package because
>   it is considered so basic that it
>   belongs in the base package.

This applies to Scala 2.7

In Scala 2.8, the collections classes have been reorganized, and now the `::` class lives in `scala.collection.immutable`, and the name `scala.::` is a type alias for `scala.collection.immutable.::`.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.RC5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_18).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.getClass
res0: java.lang.Class[_] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

scala> scala.::
res1: collection.immutable.::.type = scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon$@6ce5d622
```

Answer (score 1):

if you call getClass method on the

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,3,45)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 45)

scala> val seq = Seq(1,2,3,4,5)
seq: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> list.getClass
res13: Class[_ <: List[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

scala> seq.getClass
res14: Class[_ <: Seq[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
```

That’s because scala.collection.immutable.List is an abstract class, and it comes with two implementations: the scala.Nil class and scala.::. In Scala, :: is a valid identifier, and you could use it to name a class. Nil represents an empty list, and scala.:: represents any nonempty list.